# Add-comment box placeholder text ends mid sentence

Tags: bug, status-completed

When the add-comment box is not focused it has a placeholder text, which ends mid sentence:

```
"Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. 
Avoid comments like "
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k8MU.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next deployment